# How to write the program to compare two audio files

Tags: audio-processing, programming

I want to make the program which would take one file and check the similarity with other. It would be music/melody file, and the program would ignore small deviations between two of them similarly to Shazam and other music recognition software. 
I worked with C, C++, C# and Python but I have no experience in signal processing and I don't know which programming language is suitable for this task. I've search the Internet for the solution but couldn't find it. 
If anyone has some experience with this, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @G John, one of the Shazam authors has published a paper describing how it works. Obviously he didn't go into details explaining every aspect of it but it should be enough to get you started. The `dsp` side of things is the easy part (in my opinion). It's still a clever algorithm ( https://github.com/papers-we-love/papers-we-love/blob/master/audio_comp_sci/shazam-audio-search-algorithm.pdf )